# The program or feature "\??\D:\data\setup.exe" cannot start or run due to the incompatibility with 64-bit version of windows"

Tags: gaming

I was trying to install a very old game and when i click the setup button this message appears. The program or feature "\??\D:\data\setup.exe" cannot start or run due to the incompatibility with 64-bit version of windows"
please me solve this problem.

Comment: Run in compatibility mode and see?

Answer (score 2):

[64-bit Windows does not support 16-bit applications](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896458). So if the game really is as old as you claim, it must be a 16-bit application which cannot be run under Windows 64-bit.

Try to find a 32-bit version of the game you're trying to install. Else you'll have to run the game within a [Virtual system](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [an emulator like DOSBOX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dosbox/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Universal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract) to pack the installer out, but this may result not installing important registry keys of the program